# How to save a 2 dimensinal array in the form of text file and then read it from the text file using python?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, file

I have a 2-dimensional array. I want to save this array in a text file and then I want to retrieve this array using python.

My code:

```
np.savetxt('points.txt',final_points)
f=open('points.txt','r')
new_final_points=f.read()
```

This saves the whole array as a string in new_final_points.
I want it back in the array form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use numpy's `np.loadtxt` in very much the same way as `np.savetxt`

Example:

```py
np.savetxt("points.txt")
array = np.loadtxt("points.txt")
```